# How to write a type for array for multiple discriminating unions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have `events` that are distinguished by using discriminating union types. However, when I write `handlers` for those, and use the `handlers` in a function that accepts an `array` of `handlers` for those `events`, the first `handler` in the array determines the value of the generic type, thus the other handlers don't match the signature of the array.

Here's an example and [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=50&pln=1&pc=1#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-WUkSq9WaqXIHXoPUKoslk3l4Aq5xEq02zH2x3O12uaDRT3e4lLEkEMkEC1bHYrNaHY6nc408GdMrB2G0-krq6h5GEIA)

```js
type EventTypes = 
  | { 
    type: "FIRST",
    someProp: string,
  }
  | {
    type: "SECOND",
    otherProp: string
  }

type EventHandler<TEvent extends { type: string; [key: string]: any }> = (
  event: TEvent,
) => any

function someFunctionAcceptsHandlers<
  TEvent extends { type: string; [key: string]: any }
>(handlers: EventHandler<TEvent>[]) {
  // do something here
}

const handler1: EventHandler<
  Extract<EventTypes, {type: "FIRST"}>
> = (event) => {
  console.log(event.type)
  console.log(event.someProp) // << Notice the difference
}

const handler2: EventHandler<
  Extract<EventTypes, {type: "SECOND"}>
> = (event) => {
  console.log(event.type)
  console.log(event.otherProp) // << Notice the difference
}

someFunctionAcceptsHandlers([handler1, handler2])
// Error occurs here                   ^ 
// Type 'EventHandler<{ type: "SECOND"; otherProp: string; }>' 
//   is not assignable to type 
//   'EventHandler<{ type: "FIRST"; someProp: string; }>'.
```

**Possible workarounds** (not really solutions)

- change the type of the eventHandlers into `EventHandler<Extract<EventTypes, {type: "FIRST" | string}>>` to clarify that this handler can accept anything of type EventTypes, but then I'd just remove the whole `Extract` part
- add generic type argument to the `someFunctionAcceptsHandlers` like so: `someFunctionAcceptsHandlers<EventTypes>`. But that doesn't work, because now nothing matches

```
Type 'EventHandler<{ type: "FIRST"; someProp: string; }>' 
is not assignable to type 'EventHandler<EventTypes>'.
  Type 'EventTypes' is not assignable to type 
  '{ type: "FIRST"; someProp: string; }'.
    Property 'someProp' is missing in type 
    '{ type: "SECOND"; otherProp: string; }' but required in type 
    '{ type: "FIRST"; someProp: string; }'.
```

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy5ZxW) work for you?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please edit the code example to show the use cases where this doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @jcalz nice solution!

Comment: @jcal wow! This is brilliant! Thanks, this does satisfy all my requirements

Comment: @jcalz you have probably forgot to write an answer here

Comment: When someone calls me @jcal I am not alerted